# How Object files get linked in C? Explain this particular situation

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Why do they print different values. Please explain in details.
One file is:

```
    /* boo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
char main;
void p2()
{
printf("0x%X\n", main);
}
```

Another file is:

```
/* foo6.c */ 
void p2(void);

int main()
{
    char ch = main;
    p2();
    printf("Main address is 0x%x\n",main);
    printf("Char value is 0x%x\n",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected p2 and char ch to print same values, but they are printing very different values.
Output is:

```
0x55
Main address is 0x401110
Char value is 0x10
```

I cannot conclude the reasons behind such values (Main and char values worked as expected, but not p2 output as I mentioned earlier)

Comment: `char` is probably 8 bit and signed. A pointer is probably 32/64 bit and unsigned. Go figure.

Comment: Notice how the value of "Char" is the same as the last byte (2 nibbles) of "Main", namely `0x10`.

Comment: In one object file, main is  a char, while in the other its a function pointer. I don't think linking the two together is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char ch = main;` just truncates the pointer to a char. Implementation defined, but you getting the lower 8-bits makes sense.

Now `char main` (uninitialized) in another compilation unit fools the compiler by memory-mapping a function pointer on a `char` directly, without any conversion: that's *undefined behaviour*.

(and the formats used by `printf` don't match the data types...)

try that: `char main=12;` you'll get a multiply defined symbol `main`...

Comment: Undefined behavior is indeed the bottom line.  Moreover, it should be noted that the behavior is undefined even with the original code, wherein boo.c does not provide an initializer for its `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Its indeed undefined behavior, just to add - why do you see `0x55` from `p2`, look at dis-assembly:

```
p2:
...
0x40052a: movzx   eax,BYTE PTR [rip+0x17]        # 0x400548 <main>
...
main:
0x400548: push    rbp
```

gcc generates code which takes first byte at function main address, effectively it is opcode for `push rbp`, which is `0x55`

you can rewrite p2 code like this to understand it better:

```
int main();
void p2() {
    char t = ((char*)&main)[0];
    printf("%x\n", t);
}
```